# Is it possible to cancel an exception that has not been caught?

Tags: python, exception

I have a situation where I want to utilise a custom sys.excepthook. When a program throws an exception the sys.except hook gets called and does some stuff.

Example:

```
import sys
def ehook(exctype, value, traceback):
    t = 'Keys'
    if exctype == AttributeError and value.args[0].split("'")[1] == t:
        print "t %s" % (t,)
    else:
        sys.__excepthook__(exctype, value, traceback)

sys.excepthook = ehook



class Keys():
    @staticmethod
    def x():
        print "this is Keys.x()"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Keys.x()
    Keys.noexist()
    print "I want to continue here and beyond..."
```

Is there a way I can cancel the active exception in the excepthook so it does not cause the program to exit?

Comment: Do you want to handle all exceptions, or `KeyError`s, `AttributeError`s, and the like?

Comment: Just the AttributeError. What I am trying to achieve is a somehow allow a user to call things like Keys.group(), Keys.revert() etc., where the Keys methods group(), revert() are undefined but I can capture those undefined method names and use them to return back something using those names. Like return str("keyname_" + the_undefined_name").  I am wanting to avoid having to wrap in try except clauses.

Comment: @DaveKierans: It sounds like you're looking for `__getattr__`.  See my edited answer.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks: I'll try this and see if I can get it to work - thus far my first attempt is giving me an infinite loop. I think I need the work on the return from the _getattr__ so it return something useful that is callable but does what I want. I will keep experimenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  By the time `sys.excepthook` is called, the exception is already uncaught at the top level and the program will exit after `sys.excepthook` does its work.  (See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook).)  In general exceptions aren't resumable in Python: you have handle them where you catch them, you can't just continue from where they happened.  See [this thread](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/629766/) for a bit of discussion.

Edit: Based on your comment, it doesn't sound like you're trying to catch all exceptions in your whole program.  You just want to catch undefined attribute lookups on certain objects.  If that's the case, just define a [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) on your class.