# how to catch all uncaught exceptions and go on?

Tags: python, exception, traceback

> **EDIT**: after reading the comments and the answers I realize that what I want to do does not make much sense. What I had in mind was that I
>   have some places in my code which may fail (usually some `requests`
>   calls which may not go though) and I wanted to catch them instead of
>   putting a `try:` everywhere. My specific problem was such that I would
>   not care if they fail and would not influence the rest of the code
>   (say, a watchdog call).
>
> I will leave this question for posterity as an ode to "think about the
>   real problem first, then ask"

I am trying to handle all uncaught (otherwise unhandled) exceptions:

```
import traceback
import sys

def handle_exception(*exc_info):
    print("--------------")
    print(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info))
    print("--------------")

sys.excepthook = handle_exception
raise ValueError("something bad happened, but we got that covered")
print("still there")
```

This outputs

```
--------------
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "C:/Users/yop/.PyCharm50/config/scratches/scratch_40", line 10, in <module>\n    raise ValueError("something bad happened, but we got that covered")\n', 'ValueError: something bad happened, but we got that covered\n']
--------------
```

So, while the raise was indeed caught,  it did not work the way I thought: a call to `handle_exception`, then resume with the `print("still there")`.

<del>How can I do so?</del>

Comment: You can't, and this is not a sensible thing to do - what if the bad thing means that your variable is not set? Should you run the next line, which now `NameError`s?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy

Comment: @jonrsharpe: after some actual thinking - yes, I guess so. I will update my question with that thinking.

Comment: FWIW, I also found [*Is it possible to cancel an exception that has not been caught?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14993129/2301450). Seems pretty close to your question.

Comment: @vaultah: good find - a very similar question, and the first part of the answer is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this because Python calls `sys.excepthook` [for *uncaught* exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook).

> In an interactive session this happens just before control is returned to the prompt; in a Python program this happens just before the program exits.

There's no way to resume the execution of the program or "supress" the exception in `sys.excepthook`.

The closest I can think of is

```
try:
    raise ValueError("something bad happened, but we got that covered")
finally:
    print("still there")
```

There's no `except` clause, therefore `ValueError` won't be caught, but the `finally` block is guaranteed to be executed. Thus, the exception hook will still be called and `'still there'` will be printed, but the `finally` clause will be executed *before* `sys.excepthook`:

> If an exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the
>   exception is temporarily saved. The finally clause is executed. If
>   there is a saved exception it is re-raised at the end of the finally
>   clause.

(from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally))

Comment: *There's no way to resume the execution of the program or "supress" the exception in `sys.excepthook`.* This.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after:

```
import traceback
import sys

try:
    raise ValueError("something bad happened, but we got that covered")
except Exception:
    print("--------------")
    print(traceback.format_exception(sys.exc_info()))
    print("--------------")
print("still there")
```